# MySQL select query finds a result that shouldn't be found in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, for a school assignment I have to make a website. This website must contain a functionality that gets articles out of a database.

I can, for example, show article 1 with *domain.com/content/article/1/*.

However, when I use a URL like this *domain.com/content/article/2aadd/* it still shows article 2.
Even *../10aadd/* shows article 10.
If I try to request an article that doesn't exist with like *../11aadd* (article 11 doesn't exist) it will show an error that it can't find the article, like it should.

---

I use URL rewriting so a URL like this *domain.com/content/article/1/* is rewritten as *domain.com/index.php?c=content&a=article&arg=1*

I use a database class, every select query is sent to a select-query method. It accepts the following parameters:

- $q - the query
- $params - an array with parameters for the query
- $fetch - the fetching mode

The following parameters are sent in order to show an article:

- *select title,content from PHP2b_OOP_EIND_Articles where id=:id and enabled=1*
- array("id"=>$_GET["arg"])
- *assoc*

In every call of this method a new statement is being prepared and executed with the *$params* array as parameter.

---

I've dumped out the *$params* array and it does show the entire string (e.g. 10aadd).

I've tried it without the clean URL.

I've tried to look it up but I couldn't find anything.

---

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your MySQL table's `id` column is defined as an integer data type.

You're experiencing a peculiarity of MySQL when it coerces a string data type to an integer.

```
select CAST('10aaadd' AS INT)
```

gives back the value `10`, strangely enough.

Your query, after variable substitution, says `WHERE id = '10aaadd'`.

Because MySQL implicitly casts that string to an int, it finds the row with the `id` value of `10`.

Weird, huh?

If you expect only integers in a $_GET or $_POST parameter, it's a good idea to check for that and throw an error if the values you receive don't match expectations.  [PHP's `is_numeric()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) can do that for you.